# Web page overlays

Tags: html

When one goes to Google images, then selects an image it creates an overlay over the images webpage. On the left there is the page and on the right is a panel made by Google. What is the name for that panel? Anyone have any tutorials on how to make something similar.

I want to have my text on the left, and the webpage on the right. What are the legalities behind this? In particular I want to do it over Google search results. Sot that the search results are on the right, and my content would be on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a frame.

You can make one with the `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tags, or by fetching the content of a remote site (via JavaScript or server-side), and then integrating it into your site layout.

The legalities depend on the method you use.  If you use a `frame` tag, you're not touching the remote site at all, so you're almost certainly OK.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use it to make some search enhancing tools.

Answer (score 1):

IFrame is few old technologies, but still alive ;)
mostly end-user block it with some usual as ADBlock

nowadays better to use HTML/JS

and if you are few lazy for pure coding, I'd like to advice to use some js/html framework.

so take a look [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/overlay.html).

Regards
Eugene